# how to use existing buttons in vbox panel in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch

After having a look around for how to make a vertical tabbar dock to the right of a panel for ages, it doesn't seem like something it supports. So I am looking for the best way to manually achieve what I want.

I want to use as much core sencha stuff as possible. I've looked at a few things but am currently tinkering with a vbox panel with buttons as the items, with the idea that I add some extra styling to them to make it look more like a tab from a tab panel.

Forgive me for the vague partial code below, but I have been adding and removing various options and have got a little lost. Hopefully it will give you an idea of how I am trying to achieve a right docked vertical tab panel though.

I'd appreciate pointers on how to steer the UI back towards the look of the TabPanel or an alternative.

Thanks in advance

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    dock: 'right',
    width: 120,
    height: '100%',
    layout: {
      type: 'vbox',
      align: 'start'
    },
    ui: 'light',
    defaults: {
      xtype: 'button',
      margin: '10 10 0 0',
      iconMask: true,
      ui: 'plain',
      color: '#fff'
    },
    items: [
      {
        text: 'test',
        iconCls: 'time',
      },
      {
        text: 'test2',
        iconCls: 'time',
      }


    ],
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the source of Ext.TabBar. It extends Ext.Panel and there isn't much magic/code going on.
You might need to tweak the CSS-side as well.
You seem to be on the right track already, though.

Comment: thanks steffen. with the requirement being slightly non-standard I just had to except that it wasn't a directly config-able option from one of the core objects. the latest design doesn't actually require this but it was good to take the time to read through TabBar, I normally don't read through the library until I'm debugging an error. It's something i'll do more of